# Conformal bootstrap - why do we only compute bounds for the dimensions of scalar operators in the OPE, and not for nonzero spin operators?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, computational-physics, conformal-field-theory, phase-transition, ising-model

I am trying to understand the use of the conformal bootstrap algorithm to determine bounds on the operators appearing in the $\phi \times \phi$ OPE in a conformal field theory.

I understand the process is as follows (from the TASI lectures by Simmons-Duffin, https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.07982):

1. Make a guess about the spins $l$ and dimensions $\Delta$ of operators appearing in the OPE
2. Search for a supporting plane given this set of operators
3. If such a supporting plane is found, crossing symmetry cannot be satisfied and the set of operator dimensions and spins must be expanded.

My confusion is about step 1. Both Simmons-Duffin and Rattazzi et al (arxiv.org/abs/0807.0004) take a guess in the following form:

- For spin $l > 0$, operators can appear with every dimension, bounded from below by their unitarity bound.
- For scalar operators, we assume a lowest-dimension scalar $\Delta_0$ in the OPE.

Thus we can place an upper bound on the lowest-dimension *scalar* primary in the OPE.

But why don't we do the same thing for the nonzero spin operators? It seems that it would be logical to consider each spin in term, letting all dimensions for the other spin operators appear from their unitarity bounds, and thus working out an upper bound on the lowest-dimension primary in the OPE for each spin, not just $l=0$.

Similarly, why don't the same techniques seem to get used to attempt to find an upper bound on the dimension of certain operators?

Why isn't this done? Is it a matter of gaining little information due to the fast convergence of the conformal blocks for higher-valued spins, or something else entirely?

Comment: People compute bounds on the gap for spinning operators quite a bit. See https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.6064 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.1803 for instance.